# Handle array as an input user defined variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Am using a array value as an input parameter to my script and it is not printing the value rather it is printing each letter. How to handle this in JMeter.

The Input Variable's value is `["Inflammation","Perf","Test_Study"]`

[image]

When I am trying to print it is printing as below,

```
 2023-06-06 21:58:01,450 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2023-06-06 21:58:01,450 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2023-06-06 21:58:01,450 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2023-06-06 21:58:01,453 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2023-06-06 21:58:01,453 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2023-06-06 21:58:01,453 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2023-06-06 21:58:01,453 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2023-06-06 21:58:01,453 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2023-06-06 21:58:01,454 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2023-06-06 21:58:01,454 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2023-06-06 21:58:01,792 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->[
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->"
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->I
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->n
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->f
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->l
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->a
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->m
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->m
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->a
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->t
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->i
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->o
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->n
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->"
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->,
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->"
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->P
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->e
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->r
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->f
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->"
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->,
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->"
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->T
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->e
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->s
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->t
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->_
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->S
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->t
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->u
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->d
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->y
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->"
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.e.J.StudyNameProcesser: --------------->]
2023-06-06 21:58:01,811 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2023-06-06 21:58:01,812 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2023-06-06 21:58:01,812 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-06-06 21:58:01,812 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to say what exactly is wrong without seeing your code, you could try out the following approach:

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('excludeStudyName')).each {  entry ->
    log.info(entry)
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

It should be achieve in this way,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

String tempExcludeStudyName = vars.get('excludeStudyName'); 

def sNameArray = new JsonSlurper().parseText(tempExcludeStudyName);

for(tempName in sNameArray) {
    log.info("Name :"+ tempName)
}
```

[image]